# knockout nested arrays paging, how can I keep track of the variables or find the parent record

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js, paging

I currently have an observable array, that has an observable array as one of it's items.  I use this to create a "twisty" type format with tables.

when you click on an element I call an ajax statement to fill the e.child array

my question is how can I do paging and sorting on the child array.  currently I keep the variables (currentpage, max page, etc) in the parent array.  but when I click on the pages, I cant seem to figure out how to get to those.

some pseudo code below.  when I click on the paging, I get the page number, but I can't see how to get to the parent record that has all my paging information.

```
        <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: parentarray">
        <tr>
        <td> <span class="expandable" data-bind="text:GroupByTxt, click: myp.click_pgroup "></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr data-bind="visible: detail().length > 0">
                <td >
                    <div  data-bind="if: detail().length>0">
                        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
                            <li data-bind="click: myp.priorPage" data-page="Total_Sales"><a>&laquo;</a></li>
                    <!-- ko foreach: darray-->

                    <li ><a data-bind="text: $data+1, click: myp.gotopage" data-page="detail.Total_Sales"></a></li>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                            <li data-bind="click: myp.nextPage" data-page="detail.Total_Sales"><a>&raquo;</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                     <tbody data-bind="foreach:detail "></tbody>
                     <table>
                    </td>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: It will really help if you post JSFiddle.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that as it will be very time consuming to make in this instance.

Comment: @user1813251 - I guess in your case you will spend more time to explain your issue then making an jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything without JSFiddle example, but maybe you are tolking about [$parent](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-2-using-index-parent-and-other-context-properties) accessor?